# How to check if the argument passed is a string in c?

Tags: c

I have the following code :

```
void test(int N)
{
    printf("%d", N);

}
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    test("");
    return 0;
}
```

I have a function test that expects an integer argument, but in the main when I call the function I give a string argument and c converts it to a integer and prints it for me. But what I want is that if someone passes a string than I give an error. How to check whether the argument is a string though ?

Thanks !

Comment: You should turn on compiler warnings and listen to them. I can't believe this even compiles, since it's an implied cast from `char*` to `int`.

Comment: Make sure you always have a prototype in scope for every function that you define or use (including the function `test()`) — and that you are paying attention to your compiler's warnings and fixing them all.

Comment: It was not about fixing, I wanted to put a check for any invalid arguments and than return the appropriate error

Comment: You fix that sort of problem at compile time by ensuring that you don't abuse your functions.  At run time, you shouldn't be able to pass an invalid value to the function because the types were checked at compile time.

Comment: Well in this case it was some user who would put in the arguments, which could be valid or invalid. I cannot control the user :) But I get it, this is something c cant help me with.

Comment: @KuberKaul: A user cannot generate a call to a function with an argument of the wrong type, unless by "user" you mean the programmer. The error is in your code; `test("");` is invalid.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: It's not really an implied conversion (not cast) at all.  It's simply invalid -- more precisely, a constraint violation. The standard says a compiler must diagnose the error; it doesn't say that it should generate a conversion from `char*` to `int`.

Comment: There is no way to detect this, since everything is valid as an integer. Formally, there is no way to detect this because code which does this invokes undefined behavior, at which point all bets are off. Either way, the answer is "it can't be done". Welcome to C. We hope you enjoy your stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I want is that if someone passes a string than I give an error

That's not really your problem.  Most compilers will give a warning for this, I think -- presuming warnings are enabled.

The issue is that C always passes by value, but a string argument is an array, and its value is the address of the first character in the array -- a pointer, but pointer values can be treated as integers.  Again, most compilers are smart enough to catch this ambiguity, if you use them properly.

You can't completely bulletproof your code against people who use it improperly.  You write an API, you document it, but you don't have to cover cases for those who cannot use basic tools properly.

The core standard C library does not include checks of the sort you are looking for here, so it seems pointless to incorporate them into your API -- there are oodles of built-in standard commands with `int` args to which an array can be passed in the same way.  Saving someone from doing something stupid with your library won't save them from doing the exact same thing with the base C lib -- i.e., **you can't stop them from passing pointers in place of ints.  Period.**

Comment: I do get warnings but it still compiles and gives a value. I wanted to put a check on whether the argument passed is a string, in which case I want to pass invalid argument ( -EINVAL)

Comment: Just got started with c but that sounds weird. So basically, I cannot cover for cases where people might end up giving invalid argument of string in place of integer ? (except the warnings, ofcourse !)

Comment: @KuberKaul : I've added a few paragraphs describing how this is a pitfall of C generally, and since you can do exactly the same thing with core library functions, there can be no point in protecting against it -- if you user does this with your functions, they'll do it with the base C lib anyway, which does not protect against it.  As the saying goes, "you are free to shoot yourself in the foot" and that's C.  If you don't like it, don't use it.

Comment: Keep in mind C does not have the overhead of most other high level languages, and one of the things it is not paying as much for is safety.  That's the nature of the beast.  *It's slick and a little dangerous ;)*

Comment: To add to what goldilocks has said, I would argue that it's actually *detrimental* to attempt to determine whether your argument is a string or not — it is far more likely that your code will have a false positive (preventing a legitimate use of your code from working) than it is that someone's compiler won't catch their stupidity. This kind of input validation is extremely uncommon in C.

Comment: "*and its value is the address of the array -- which is an integer*" -- No. First, the value of `""` is converted to the address of the first character of the array (which hold `'\0'` in this case), not to the address of the entire array; there's a difference. Second, and most important **an address is not an integer**.

Comment: @goldilocks: Try passing a string literal to a C function that takes an `int` argument. Either the compiler will reject it (or at the very least warn about it), or you need to get a better compiler. C is more strongly typed than you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
void test(int N) { /* ... */ }

...

test("");
```

That function call is simply invalid. `test` requires an argument of type `int`, or of something that's implicitly convertible to `int` (any arithmetic type will do). `""` is a string literal; in this context, it's converted to a `char*` value which points to the `'\0'` character which is the first (and last, and only) character of the array.

There is no implicit conversion from `char*` to `int`. A conforming compiler *must* issue a diagnostic for the invalid call, and it *may* (and IMHO should) reject it outright. It's exactly as invalid as trying to take the square root of a string literal, or add 42 to a structure.

Older versions of C (before the 1989 ANSI standard) were more lax about this kind of thing, and that laxity survives into some modern compilers. It's likely that, if your compiler doesn't reject the call, it will take the address of the string literal and convert it to an `int`. The result of this conversion is largely meaningless; such a compiler really isn't doing you any favors by permitting it.

If your compiler doesn't reject, or at the very least warn about, the call, you should enable whatever options are necessary to make it do so. For gcc, for example, you might try something like:

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra filename.c
```

You can drop the `-pedantic` if you want to use gcc-specific extensions. There are several possible arguments for the `-std=` option. See the gcc documentation for more information -- or the documentation for whatever compiler you're using.

If you're asking about validating user input (i.e., input from someone running your program rather than writing C code), user input is not generally in the form of numbers. It's in the form of *text*, sequences of characters. For example, you might use the `fgets()` function to read a line of text from standard input. You can then, if you like, check whether that line has the form of an integer literal. One way to do that is to use the `sscanf` function. A quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char line[200];
    int n;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
    if (sscanf(line, "%d", &n) == 1) {
        printf("You entered %d (0x%x)\n", n, (unsigned)n);
    }
    else {
        printf("You did not enter an integer\n");
    }
}
```

But if your question is about someone writing C code that calls a function you provide, the compiler will check that any arguments are of a valid type.

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach is something like this:

```
int is_integer( const char *s )
{
    if( *s == '-' || *s == '+' ) s++;
    while( isdigit(*s) ) s++;
    return *s == 0;
}
```

That will tell you if all characters are digits, with an optional sign.  It's not particularly robust, however.  It can't handle whitespace, and it doesn't check the integer is in the valid range.

However, it might be enough for your needs.

Example:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int val;

    if( argc <= 1 || !is_integer(argv[1]) ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Syntax: %s val\n\nWhere val is an integer\n", argv[0] );
        return 1;
    }

    val = strtol( argv[1], NULL, 10 );
    test(val);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that once you've determined your input looks like an integer, you can use `strtol` to convert it to an integer.  You don't really need to do the test, as the function will return 0 if parsing fails.  But you might want to distinguish between an actual 0 *vs* invalid input.

Comment: Well I might not have been clear, basically I want to check whether the argument passed is a "string", in which case I want to return -EINVAL . So I was confused how to check whether the arg passed is string ?

Answer (score 0):

Compile with `-Wall` and `-Werror` and your problem will magically go away.

```
gcc -Wall -Werror file.c
```